# Can't start busybox pod

Tags: kubernetes

If I start a Kubernetes pod like this, it fails:

```
k run bb --image=busybox
```

```
k describe pod bb

...
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling  14m (x35 over 164m)     kubelet  Pulling image "busybox"
  Warning  BackOff  4m23s (x736 over 164m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

What is the reason?

The `run` commands works fine for the `nginx` image.

Answer (score 2):

`busybox` is not a server. It does not start the endless "listen for input" loop.

The same happens for the `alpine` image.

But you can create an endless loop like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: bb
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'while true; do date; sleep 3; done']
    name: bb
```

```
k apply -f bb.yaml
```

```
k describe pod bb

...
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  6s    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/bb to minikube-m02
  Normal  Pulling    5s    kubelet            Pulling image "busybox"
  Normal  Pulled     3s    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 2.256262371s
  Normal  Created    3s    kubelet            Created container bb
  Normal  Started    3s    kubelet            Started container bb
```

And you can see the logs:

```
guettli@p15:~/.kube$ k logs bb 

Fri Apr  8 20:38:30 UTC 2022
Fri Apr  8 20:38:33 UTC 2022
Fri Apr  8 20:38:36 UTC 2022
```